# How to "Get the Item URL of the SharePoint List Item(On Premise) " and to add it in the Data Table

Tags: c#, sharepoint, listitem

I am trying to get the List Item URL of the Item in the SharePoint (On Premise) list. Will the Item URL is in the "Look Up". If it is present in the Look Up, then what is the name(Key) of the lookup holding the Item URL(value). Help me in adding the URL to the Data Table as I have requested.

I have checked the List Item Collection which I have got as the result of getting the SP List items. Is there any way to get the List Item URL.

```
 System.Data.DataTable DT = new DataTable();
                SP.List oList = SP_List.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(ListName);
                CamlQuery cQuery = new CamlQuery();
                cQuery.ViewXml = "@<View><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>";
                ListItemCollection ListCollection = oList.GetItems(cQuery);
                SP_List.Load(ListCollection);
                SP_List.ExecuteQuery();

                for (int i = 0; i < ColumnName.Length; i++)
                    DT.Columns.Add(ColumnName[i], System.Type.GetType("System.String"));

                for (int i = 0; i < LookUp.Length; i++)
                    DT.Columns.Add(LookUp[i], System.Type.GetType("System.String"));

                foreach (ListItem value in ListCollection)
                {
                    DataRow dr = DT.NewRow();
                    for (int i = 0; i < ColumnName.Length; i++)
                        dr[ColumnName[i]] = value[ColumnName[i]].ToString();
                    for (int i = 0; i < LookUp.Length; i++)
                        dr[LookUp[i]] = (((Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue)value[LookUp[i]])?.LookupValue).ToString();
                        DT.Rows.Add(dr);
```

This is the present code, I am having to get the Values I have needed. I am also trying to add the "Item URl" in this Data Table, help me in getting and adding the value to the Data Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, all you want is the list item url? You can access the ServerRelativeUrl via
`SP.ListItem.File.ServerRelativeUrl`

i.e.

```
ctx.load(listItem.File)
ctx.executequery()
console.log(listITem.File.ServerRelativeUrl)
```

(sorry I wrote this in jsom not csom, the code is almost the same though)

Your code looks overly complicated for what you're trying to do. I'd maybe consider simplifying it.

Comment: While this works for document libraries, this does not work for lists

Comment: @Mx For list items you can use properties such as ViewFormUrl or EditFormUrl but typically you need to get the URL to the edit/view form then pass ?ID=[your id here]. This is because list items are just data, you need a form to render the data.

Comment: Obviously. This comment was just intended to help people that get here by searching "how to get the item url of a sp list item".